# Cache/preload SVG files react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

I'm using [React Native SVG](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) and using the implementation with svg files ([url to implementation](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/blob/main/USAGE.md#use-with-svg-files)).

Is there any way to preload/cache this svgs? I have a component that imports several SVGs and it freezes because it's loading all those icons.

I've searched but got nothing (AppLoading from expo doesn't work for SVGs)

Answer (score 0):

you can use "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image" for caching images or similar one.